# Is the Master Data Services Metadata model deprecated or not?

Tags: sql-server, metadata, master-data-services

In 2012 Microsoft tells us that we should not use the Metadata model within SQL Server Master Data Services as it is a deprecated feature. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231001.aspx

In 2014 it seems to be back with no mention of any U-turn.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487016.aspx

It seems like the perfect place to manage information regarding the scheduled imports into my models but I don't want to rely on it if it is to be whipped away in a future version.

Does anyone have a definitive answer?

Answer (score 1):

Definitive - No. Suggestive - Yes.

When looking at the parent level of your second link; [Master Data Services Features and Tasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231022.aspx) the reference to metadata and the ability to navigate to the metadata page has been removed for version 2016. It suggests that Microsoft are still removing the feature.

You can still reach http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487016.aspx directly and see information for 2016

[image]